# indy TCPSERVER.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := indytextencoding_utf8 is causing crashing in android

Tags: encoding, indy, tcpserver

i am trying to establish a link over the internet to commit some kind of text messages to an abroad indy tcp based server
those messages contains sometimes some arabic letters or content

from pc everything is ok, but when i come to use it on android by establishing

```
tcpserver.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := indytextencoding_utf8;
```

the application crashes(it just closes) on loading without giving any errors.

am i missing something here ?? why this should be an error ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The only way that single line of code can crash is if either the `IOHandler` is not valid (are you connected first?), or the ICONV library is failing internally, or ARC is not being handled correctly. You didn't say which exact version of Indy you are using. Or if `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8()` still crashes when called by itself. So it is really hard to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Can you put a `try..except` around the code and prevent the app from closing?  Can you run the app in the debugger and see the call stack when the crash happens?

Comment: Guys .. im sorry it was my miistake.. i forgot that showmessage on android is asynch.. and so the command was executed before the connection is established.. so thank you remy for pointing that out